# Proper Database Design: One table to Multiple Objects

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Forgive me. I believe it is a wrong title. but here goes.

Let's put an instance that we have 3 Objects. **USERS**, **ITEMS**, and **WORK**. These 3 objects may contain multiple **Notes**

So I formulated a database design which I tried and it works but I know it's not efficient by performance and I think it's improper.

[image]

As you can see in `notes` table, `notes.tag` is the string identifier of the tagged table. `users`, `items`, `work`. The `notes.tag_id` is the ID of the row of the object.

Below is the **Notes Table** with its sample Value

```
+----+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--+
| ID | TAG   | TAG_ID | MESSAGE                     |  |
+----+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--+
| 1  | items | 1      | Lorem Ipsum                 |  |
+----+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--+
| 2  | items | 1      | Dolor sit Amet              |  |
+----+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--+
| 3  | users | 1      | consectetur adipiscing elit |  |
+----+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--+
```

For me, this is quite efficient(and lazy) but I don't really know if this is the proper. Do you have any proper suggestions?

Comment: OO and databases do not map well into each other.  There is no 'perfect' way to do what you want; there are multiple 'adequate' ways.

Comment: OO is for decomposing systems into communicating state machines. State machines *have* state, but state machines are more than just state. The desire to map between OO and databases is naive, based in a lack of understanding of both disciplines. A DBMS is a perfectly fine object with which other objects can exchange messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a separate NOTE_USERS, NOTE_ITEM, NOTE_WORK table. Then, you don't need the `tag` field and `tag_id` can be a true foreign key.

In an ER diagram, I would make the NOTE_* entities to be a disjoint `is-a` of a NOTE entity. However, I would not "materialize" it as a table in the database.

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph. Being able to enforce proper FK constraints is important to database integrity. However, I don't agree woth your comment about the ER diagram. If NOTE_USERS, NOTE_ITEM and NOTE_WORK are self-contained and each include a message attribute, then there's no reason to draw them as subtypes of some NOTE entity. The value of a supertype is to unify subsets and to implement common attributes and relationships, but without a matching table to generate disjoint id values, record common attributes and serve as reference for FK constraints, why show a supertype at all?

Comment: @reaanb The `message` attribute is common among all NOTE_* entities.

Comment: My point is that there's no reason to model a supertype if you're not going to "materialize" it.

Comment: So basically, I am to create a different table on each objects? `work_notes`, `items_notes`, and `users_notes`

Comment: @AaronAlfonso Yes, exactly.